# how to shuffle a php array but keep the index in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, shuffle

i have an array and its data are displayed in a grid using a foreach loop.
the index of the foreach is used as part of url for each entry in the grid.

```
$i=0;   
foreach ($array as $grid) {
 $name = $grid->name;
 $address = $grid->address;
 echo '<li> <a href="javascript:myclick('.$i.');" title="">' . $name . '</a> </li>';
 $i++;
}
```

i'd like to display the array in random order so i used shuffle();
but the index gets destroyed and the links break.
i have been looking around for 2 days and tried many different kinds of functions that were supposed to keep the index untouched but with no luck.
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

safer shuffle the real keys of an array

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
shuffle($keys);
foreach($keys as $i) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the index instead:

```
$index = range(0, sizeof($array));
shuffle($index);
foreach ($index as $i) {
    // $array[$i], $i 
}
```

You got the idea.